# "Install App" does nothing when trying to install Mavericks

Tags: macos, software-update

I'm trying to install Mavricks and it's not working.

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NBExs0UcJ_0&feature=youtu.be

I already did a system update.
I'm currently on lion.

[image]

Says it's paused in launchpad.

Answer (score 1):

It could be that the servers are so overwhelmed with people downloading the new operating system that you have nothing wrong other than being caught in a stampede.

I would say you might try again in 30 minutes and then back off doubling the time you wait until you get a good download.

Comment: The icon and button in app store just changed to "downloading". I wish that they'd change the page in the app store to some kind of loading bar. It's pretty janky that you have to go to launchpad to see the progress.